# How to check device compatibility for finger print authentication in android

Tags: android, authentication, fingerprint

I am working with finger print authentication using android 6.0 api. 
My requirement is, if current device is supports finger print authentication, then I will go through finger print authentication else will use normal way to login the application.

So, any one can tell me, how to check device compatibility for finger print authentication in android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You have to use method `isHardwareDetected` on `FingerprintManager` class.

> Determine if fingerprint hardware is present and functional. Returns
>   true if hardware is present and functional, false otherwise.

```
// Check if we're running on Android 6.0 (M) or higher
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    //Fingerprint API only available on from Android 6.0 (M)
    FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
    if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) { 
        // Device doesn't support fingerprint authentication     
    } else if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) { 
        // User hasn't enrolled any fingerprints to authenticate with 
    } else { 
        // Everything is ready for fingerprint authentication 
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add permission to access fingerprint functions in AndroidManifest.
Since API 28:

```
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
```

Before API28:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

**With Support Library**

If you don't want to check Build.VERSION, it's also possible to check on device lower than Android 6.0 with Support Library

Add dependency:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0"
```

And use `FingerprintManagerCompat` class as this:

```
FingerprintManagerCompat fingerprintManagerCompat = FingerprintManagerCompat.from(context);

if (!fingerprintManagerCompat.isHardwareDetected()) { 
    // Device doesn't support fingerprint authentication     
} else if (!fingerprintManagerCompat.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) { 
    // User hasn't enrolled any fingerprints to authenticate with 
} else { 
    // Everything is ready for fingerprint authentication 
}
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" /> is deprecated.
Use  <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" /> now.

Comment: In API 28 FingerprintManager and FingerprintManagerCompat are deprecated. Are there replacement classes in 28 that have the isHardwareDetected and hasEnrolledFingerprints methods or equivalents?

Comment: @Nirav yes, use <uses-feature> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element

Answer (score 6):

Just a follow up to LaurentY's answer. 
You need a permission to access the finger print scanner. And for that you need to add this to your Manifest.

API 27 and before

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

API 28 and later

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
```

Answer (score 3):

This method Works for all Android versions and also check for permission

```
 private boolean isSensorAvialable() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(AppContext, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        AppContext.getSystemService(FingerprintManager.class).isHardwareDetected();
            } else {
                return FingerprintManagerCompat.from(AppContext).isHardwareDetected();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

implementing BiometricPrompt no permission is necessary:

```
    FingerprintManagerCompat fingerprintManagerCompat = FingerprintManagerCompat.from (context);

if (! fingerprintManagerCompat.isHardwareDetected ()) {
     // Device doesn't support fingerprint authentication
} else if (! fingerprintManagerCompat.hasEnrolledFingerprints ()) {
     // User hasn't enrolled any fingerprints to authenticate with
} else {
     // Everything is ready for fingerprint authentication
}
    [BiometricPrompt][1]
```