# How to check fingerprint scanner without registering a fingerprint

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I am trying to check fingerprint scanner hardware but i dont want to register the fingerprint.Is it possible?

Comment: Yeah you can do.. If you fingerprint is not registered it will say "Fingerprint mismatch" error.

Comment: What does "check fingerprint scanner hardware" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare i want to the fingerprint scanner hardware is working or not

Comment: How are you defining "is working or not"? How can you tell, if you are not comparing a newly-scanned fingerprint against a registered one?

Comment: @yash786 if i not registering fingerprint , the fingerprint scanner doesnot detect anything

Comment: @TaraSinghDanu You can check below mentioned link and see whether your requirement meets or not.

Link --> http://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-add-fingerprint-authentication/

Comment: @yash786 i am using the same code, but i dont want to register a fingerprint in setting. I want to detect fingerprint sensor without registering a fingerprint.

Comment: @TaraSinghDanu But you need to register your fingerprint in setting.Other wise it will thrown an error no Fingerprint detected or Fingerprint mismatch.

Comment: @yash786 when i am not registering fingerprint ,application is not detecting fingerprint press or not throwing any error

Comment: Try this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409969/how-to-check-device-compatibility-for-finger-print-authentication-in-android