# How to check if device has fingerprint feature and then use it in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fingerprint-api

I am using this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

to check if device has fingerprint or not. Thats how I check it in kotlin

```
val fingerSensorManager = FingerSensorManager(this)
fingerSensorManager.isFingerPrintAvailable()
```

It works fine but in `Android 8 and above` it throws exception.

How can I check fingerprint and also use it in all versions? I know there is another method for Android 8 and above but I am confuse that how to implement it so that it works in every device

Answer (score 5):

**NEWEST FOR API 28**

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC"/>
```

Now, you're able to use:

```
val executor = activity.mainExecutor
val cancelListener = DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ -> })
val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt.Builder(context)
  .setTitle("Title")
  .setSubtitle("Subtitle")
  .setDescription("Description")
  .setNegativeButton("Cancel", executor, cancelListener)
  .build()
```

**THE NEXT CODE IS FOR VERSION LOWER THAN API 28**

> This class was deprecated in API level 28. See BiometricPrompt which
>   shows a system-provided dialog upon starting authentication. In a
>   world where devices may have different types of biometric
>   authentication, it's much more realistic to have a system-provided
>   authentication dialog since the method may vary by vendor/device.

I recommend you read this thread:

[How to add fingerprint authentication to your Android app](https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-add-fingerprint-authentication-to-your-android-app-747304/)

Also, follow this other thread:

[How to check device compatibility for finger print authentication in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409969/how-to-check-device-compatibility-for-finger-print-authentication-in-android)

You have to add the dependency to your ´gradle´ file

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0"
```

Basically, if I understood correctly your question, you want to know if the device has the fingerprint hardware and features. Then you might use:

```
// Check if we're running on Android 6.0 (M) or higher
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    //Fingerprint API only available on from Android 6.0 (M)
    FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = (FingerprintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
    if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected()) { 
        // Device doesn't support fingerprint authentication     
    } else if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) { 
        // User hasn't enrolled any fingerprints to authenticate with 
    } else { 
        // Everything is ready for fingerprint authentication 
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add permission to access fingerprint functions in AndroidManifest. Since API 28:

```
<uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
```

Before API28:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: Its show that `FingerprintManager`, `isHardwareDetected()` and `hasEnrolledFingerprints()` are deprecated in Java

Answer (score 3):

o new androidX library it simple

```
BiometricManager.from(activity).canAuthenticate()
```

as documetation says

> Returns BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED if the user does not have any enrolled, or BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE if none are currently supported/enabled. 
>   Returns BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS if a biometric can currently be used (enrolled and available). Value is BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS, BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE, BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED, or BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, but `canAuthenticate()` is deprecated instead I used `canAuthenticate(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK)` or `BIOMETRIC_STRONG` .

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [biometric lib](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric) from Androidx. It's still in alpha, but is working well so far. The good thing is that you do not need two implementations for a specific Android API level.

```
fun isAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    val fingerprintManager = FingerprintManagerCompat.from(context)
    return fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected && fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()
}
```